# In a Python function how to show an image and continue executing the code after plt.show()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Python 3.7 (run in PyCharm IDE), Matplotlib 3.3.1, OS: Windows PC

This is in a function so that it does have a return value. What I need is to show the image (the image window is not closed -- it just loses the "focus") and continue executing the code after **plt.show()**. My code is as follows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Image_ReadWrite(ImagePath):
  image = plt.imread(ImagePath)  # read the image as a matrix
  plt.imshow(image)
  plt.show()
  print(f'The shape of the image is: {image.shape}')
  return image.shape


Image_ReadWrite(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\logo.jpg')  # the main code
```

The problem is that **plt.show()** will open a GUI window to show the image but the **return** line won't be executed until I close the image window. I also search online for the solutions and tried **plt.draw()** (which doesn't show the image), **plt.show(block = False)** (which shows the image and immediately close it), and **plt.pause(1)** (which shows the image for 1 second; but I want the image window to be opened till I manually close it).